# Placeholder images don't work in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser

I'm making a website, but the designer hasn't built all the images yet. In Chrome, Safari, and even IE, I can use this as a placeholder image:

```
<img src="" alt="Placeholder" title="Placeholder" height="400" width="300">
```

It appears as a 400x300 box, and the alt/title text shows up inside it. In Firefox, though, the alt text is there, but the image doesn't keep the proper dimensions. Things under the image appear right after the alt text instead of a few hundred pixels below. This totally breaks the layout. Do I have to make an actual placeholder .png, or is there a way to make Firefox show placeholders with the proper dimensions?

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/qaz/pen/xLjic) demonstrating the problem. You'll notice that it doesn't work even when I add CSS height and width properties in addition to the HTML attributes.

If the problem doesn't appear for you- if the placeholder image appears 400px high- let me know in the comments what OS and FF version you're on. There's a possibility this isn't a problem for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in Firefox while removing alt attribute.

Firefox simply displays the alt text if an image can't be displayed (which is what the "alt" text is supposed to be used for). However, I think there is a way to get Firefox to do what you want:

Open up a new tab in Firefox and enter "about:config" (without the quotes) in the address bar.
Type "image" (again, without the quotes) in the "Filter" box
Make sure the "browser.display.show_image_placeholder" option is set to "true" (double-clicking it will toggle the value).

Comment: I had already checked that show_image_placeholder was true. Fascinatingly, though, removing the alt text did the trick. I'm working with a blind developer, so keeping the alt text is a priority and I'll just have to use a dummy image as a placeholder instead, but this answers my question.